# How do I pass a dynamic PHP variable from one page to another?

Tags: php, php-include, dynamic-content

I am creating 2 webpages. The first one will show a list of items. 2nd web page, I want to create a general one so that when the user clicks on an item depending upon the chosen one, 2nd page will be modified as per item. 
I just want to pass a string variable from which I can obtain rest of the the things from  database. Just like an e-commerce website.

Comment: Google GET or Sessions, then show us the code you have attempted to try

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to achieve what you want.

Some examples:

**Using GET:**

You can use a `link` to pass a variable to the next page.

Page 1:

```
<a href="yourpage2.php?variable=<?php echo $value; ?>">Page 2</a>
```

Page 2:

```
if(isset($_GET['variable'])) {
    $new_variable = $_GET['variable'];
}
```

**Using POST:**

Page 1:

```
<form method="POST" action="yourpage2.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="variable" value="<?php echo $value; ?>">
    <input type="submit" value = "Next Page">
</form>
```

Page 2:

```
if(isset($_POST['variable'])) {
   $new_variable = $_POST['variable'];
}
```

**Using COOKIE:**

Page1:

```
$_COOKIE['variable'] = $value;
```

Page 2:

```
$new_variable = $_COOKIE['varname'];
```

> When using cookies, the variable's value is stored on the client side, opposite
>   of sessions, where the value is stored on the server side.

**Using SESSION:**

Page 1:

```
$_SESSION['variable'] = $value;
```

Page 2:

```
$new_variable = $_SESSION['variable'];
```

> Notice: When using SESSIONS, do not forget to include/write
>   `session_start();` in the start of your page right after your `<?php`
>   tag on *BOTH* of your pages.